# How to populate a feature table in a GeoPackage file using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, geometry, ogc, geopackage

I want to use the binary version of GDAL to avoid programming in C or Java here. So I have created a SQL file and I want to run it using the following command :

```
ogrinfo.exe empty.gpkg -sql @my_sql_file.txt
```

I am about to populate some features in a sample table, lets name it "road".

Here is my question :

Do I have to create a BLOB out of a set of coordinates to be able to insert a polyline in my road table? If yes how should I do this?

I couldn't find any relevant document neither in GDAL nor in OGC website.

Here it is what I have got so far :

```
CREATE TABLE road (id int NOT NULL,name text(50),geom BLOB,PRIMARY KEY (id));
INSERT INTO gpkg_contents (table_name, identifier, data_type, srs_id) VALUES ( 'road', 'my_view', 'features', 4326);
INSERT INTO gpkg_geometry_columns (table_name, column_name, geometry_type_name, srs_id, z, m) values ('road', 'geom', 'POLYLINE', 4326, 0, 0);
```

Comment: What form is your "road" data in currently?  Rather than trying to roll your own gpkg writer with sql, couldn't you just use `ogr2ogr` to populate your gpkg layer directly from the "road" data?

Comment: @Luke Well, I am developing a GPKG export feature for GE Smallworld and I have the road layer data in a Smallworld database. So I need to parse them into a set SQL statements somehow. I do not want to use a shape file as a middle translation format, cause field names with length more than 10 character will be truncated. Looks like I do not have a choice but to write a java code with gdal libs and get involved with BLOB format, right?

Comment: @Luke Thanks look, please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing an intermediate sql file anyway, instead write into an intermediate format that GDAL/OGR can read which doesn't have the same field and data limitations as shapefiles, such as [CSV](https://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html) with WKT geometry. You can then use `ogr2ogr` rather than trying to roll your own gpkg writer.

The gpkg geometry storage is [WKB](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary), so you might as well just write [WKT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) to a CSV anyway.  Be careful of data types, if they're not getting recognised by OGR you can add a CSVT file (see first link).